# R In multi-summarise function, quantile not showing result properly

Tags: r, quantile

I use data.table to generate multiple functions for different columns by group. Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
# samle data
x = rnorm(30)
y = rnorm(30)+10
group = c(rep(1,11),rep(2,19))
dt = data.table(x,y,group)

my.summary = function(x) list(length(x), 
                              sum(is.na(x)), 
                              round(mean(x),3), 
                              round(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),3),
                              round(sd(x),3),
                              round(min(x),3),
                              round(quantile(x,0.25),3),
                              round(median(x),3),
                              round(quantile(x,0.75),3),
                              round(max(x),3)
                              )
dt_des = dt[, lapply(.SD, my.summary), .SDcols = colnames(df),by=group]
```

Everything works fine except the quantile functions showing:
"c(`25%` = -0.508)"
"c(`25%` = 9.654)"
"c(`75%` = 0.48)"
"c(`75%` = 10.675)"

Could anyone please help me with the problem? Thanks!

Comment: The last line show be: dt_des = dt[, lapply(.SD, my.summary), .SDcols = c("x", "y"),by=group]

Comment: Use `round(unname(quantile(x,0.25),3))` to drop the names of the vector. Is `colnames(df)` supposed to be `colnames(dt)` in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `unname` the `quantile` function:

```
my.summary = function(x) list(length(x), 
                              sum(is.na(x)), 
                              round(mean(x),3), 
                              round(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),3),
                              round(sd(x),3),
                              round(min(x),3),
                              round(unname(quantile(x,0.25)),3),
                              round(median(x),3),
                              round(unname(quantile(x,0.75)),3),
                              round(max(x),3)
)
```